# How can i select with max() function with two different group by

Tags: sql

My table is:

[image]

I wanna count, for every month, the total of access of each user in every product, aaand the total of access, for every month, for that user, ignoring products.

So, in my result, i need to show something like this: (7 distinct days in month 07/2020 for that user, 1 distinct day for produto Spark, 6 distinct days for MapReduce and 7 distinct days for Tez)
[image]

So, for month 07/2020, this user_1 has:

- 7 total access in that month
- 1 total access for Spark
- 6 total acesss for MapReduce
- 7 total access for Tez

  ```
  SELECT    max(acessos_origem) AS access_product
        , max(acessos_geral) AS acessos_geral
        , upper(USUARIO) as USUARIO
        , ORIGEM
        , MES_ANO
        , EQUIPE
        , timestamp_format( to_char(DATA, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') as DATA
         FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.USUARIO, A.ORIGEM, A.MES_ANO ORDER BY A.DATA ASC) AS acessos_origem,
                      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.USUARIO, A.MES_ANO ORDER BY A.DATA ASC) AS acessos_geral,
                      USUARIO, EQUIPE,
                      ORIGEM,
                      MES_ANO,
                      DATA
                FROM (
                    SELECT EQUIPE, USUARIO, ORIGEM, CONCAT(concat( extract(month FROM data), '/'), extract(year FROM data)) AS mes_ano, data
                    FROM db2i1c68.DADOS_USUARIOS_PLATAFORMA_BBDATA a 
                    WHERE 1=1 AND usuario = 'bigbbd01'
                     )a 
              )b WHERE 1=1
    AND MES_ANO = '7/2020' GROUP BY  upper(USUARIO) , ORIGEM, MES_ANO, EQUIPE, timestamp_format( to_char(DATA, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY')
  ```

Using this select i have the following result:
[image]
The problem is that i have to group by product, but my access_geral has to show mt the max lookin only by user/month, like i use in my partition, even if i group by in the last select.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . based on your sample data and desired results, this looks like relatively simple aggregation:

```
SELECT USUARIO, TO_CHAR(data, 'YYYY/MM') as yyyymm, product,
       COUNT(*) as num_product,
       MAX(MAX(access_count_user)) OVER (PARTITION BY USUARIO, TO_CHAR(data, 'YYYY/MM')) as num_overall
FROM db2i1c68.DADOS_USUARIOS_PLATAFORMA_BBDATA a 
GROUP BY USUARIO, TO_CHAR(data, 'YYYY/MM'), product;
```

Your query is much more complicated; the question doesn't fully explain what it is doing.

Comment: Hey Gordon, in my query i create two DENSE_RANK() columns to count distinct days, for every month, grouped by user and user/products, that way i have the total of access that user_1 has on month 07/2020 and the total of access that user_1 has on every product on that month 07/2020. In my first select i use an MAX() to catch that total of distinct days for products and month

Comment: If i use the select that you send me, i have 3 different values on num_overall in the result, but i need to show the '7' value for each 3 lines

Comment: @HesloandosSantosViana . . . I see.  The overall should be using a window function (I updated the answer).

Comment: Thank you Gordon, i dind't realize that i need to use two max() in my external select, thanks again for helping :D